# Show same page after virtual form submission from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, form-submit

I have this javascript function

```
function SaveData(index) {

    var myVirtualForm = document.createElement("form");
    myVirtualForm.setAttribute('method', "post");
    var name = $("#" + index + " a").attr('name');
    var url = "http://localhost/my_Project/communicator.php?command=save&id=" + name;
    myVirtualForm.setAttribute('action', url);

    var iframe = document.getElementById(index + "frame");
    var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var oTable = innerDoc.getElementById("reporttable");
    //alert(oTable.rows.item(0).cells.item(0).innerText);
    //gets table
    var str = "";
    var rowLength = oTable.rows.length;
    //gets rows of table
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
        //loops through rows

        var oCells = oTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        var cellLength = oCells.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++) {
            var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerText;
            var a = "";
            var b = a.concat(i.toString(), "_", j.toString());
            var obj = document.createElement("input");
            obj.setAttribute('type', "text");
            obj.setAttribute('name', b);
            obj.setAttribute('value', cellVal.toString())
            myVirtualForm.appendChild(obj);
        }
    }
    myVirtualForm.submit();
}
```

After submission we go to communicator.php, but i want to stay on same page, who will not changed.

Comment: use ajax to send data, in your virtual form.

Comment: [Getting Started - Ajax | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Do you really need to create a form?  Use ajax, construct the parameters you need the same way as you did right now but instead use ajax to call the php file

But if you really wanted to use a virtual form you can use also this so http://malsup.com/jquery/form/  it doesn't redirect the page when a form is submitted just add an id attribute to your virtual form